# c++ for loop efficiency: body vs. afterthought

Tags: c++, for-loop

I found something interesting while on leetcode and wish someone can help explain the cause:

I was basically doing merge sort and used the fast slow pointer to find the mid pointer. Here're two versions of such code snippets:

**1. update in afterthought**

```
    for (ListNode* fast=head; 
         fast->next && fast->next->next; 
         fast = fast->next->next, slow = slow->next) { }
```

**2.  update in body**

```
    for (ListNode* fast=head; fast->next && fast->next->next; ) {
        fast = fast->next->next;
        slow = slow->next;
    }
```

Why is version 2 faster than the first one?

Compiler: g++ 4.9.2

Comment: What were your benchmarks? What compiler?

Comment: Lots of missing information here..processor details, compiler details, platform, timing measurement...

Comment: yeah, you're going to have to give some details, because in gcc [they are so identical, that gcc makes one into  a jump to the other](https://godbolt.org/g/kV5kQx)

Comment: By the C++ specification these are the same (AFAIK) and there's no reason to think that the compiler should make them produce any different code. As PeterT states gcc produces identical code for these cases. You need to provide more information as the information you provided does generally not produce the result you claim. I consider this lacking minimal, complete, verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which should include information on compiler and platform to reproduce the behavior (it should also include information on the observed behavior AKA benchmark).

Comment: Sorry. As mentioned in question, I just ran into this when doing problem `sort list` on leetcode.com and the given code snippets is the only difference between my two submissions. So I don't have direct access to more details regarding to the environment. VolAnd and PeterT's answer is enough for me, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unlikely that comma operation can significantly reduce the speed of for-loop.

I have made both variants and opened disassembly (in Visual Studio 2012) for them to see difference.

1. looks as:

   ```
       for (ListNode* fast = head;
   0022545E  mov         eax,dword ptr [head]  
   00225461  mov         dword ptr [ebp-2Ch],eax  
           fast->next && fast->next->next;
   00225464  jmp         main+17Bh (022547Bh)  
           fast = fast->next->next, slow = slow->next) {
   00225466  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-2Ch]  
   00225469  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax+4]  
   0022546C  mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx+4]  
   0022546F  mov         dword ptr [ebp-2Ch],edx  
   00225472  mov         eax,dword ptr [slow]  
   00225475  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax+4]  
   00225478  mov         dword ptr [slow],ecx  
   0022547B  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-2Ch]  
   0022547E  cmp         dword ptr [eax+4],0  
   00225482  je          main+192h (0225492h)  
   00225484  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-2Ch]  
   00225487  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax+4]  
   0022548A  cmp         dword ptr [ecx+4],0  
   0022548E  je          main+192h (0225492h)  
       }
   ```
2. is:

   ```
       for (ListNode* fast = head; fast->next && fast->next->next;) {
   0024545E  mov         eax,dword ptr [head]  
   00245461  mov         dword ptr [ebp-2Ch],eax  
   00245464  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-2Ch]  
   00245467  cmp         dword ptr [eax+4],0  
   0024546B  je          main+190h (0245490h)  
   0024546D  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-2Ch]  
   00245470  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax+4]  
   00245473  cmp         dword ptr [ecx+4],0  
   00245477  je          main+190h (0245490h)  
           fast = fast->next->next;
   00245479  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-2Ch]  
   0024547C  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax+4]  
   0024547F  mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx+4]  
   00245482  mov         dword ptr [ebp-2Ch],edx  
           slow = slow->next;
   00245485  mov         eax,dword ptr [slow]  
   00245488  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax+4]  
   0024548B  mov         dword ptr [slow],ecx  
       }
   ```

Only one `jmp` is the distinction. 
Sorry, but I cannot see significant differences, so perhaps the performance problem is not in the place of that two statements.